# When to use and not to use static function?

Tags: php, oop

My colleage says static is good when you perform fixed stuff that doesn't required any extends, but one day we need to add feature on top of his code. Heck we have to modify the ori code because he used tons of static stuff and it's not flexible for us to continue.

```
class test {
    public static function test1() {
        echo 'hi';
    }
}
test::test1();
```

Why should one should use static function? When to use it and not to use static function?

Comment: Some people will argue you should *never* use static methods.  They're idiots, but still.  This question's answers would tell you more about  the opinions of the answerer than anything objective.

Comment: The best answer to this question is: it depends .. it's too broad to give a better answer.

Comment: I second @Ja͢ck statement. But your colleague should rethink his OOP style, if he's writing 'tons of static stuff'. Everything has a rhyme or reason in OOP

Comment: Basically you have to weigh OOP (object oriented programming) against COP (class oriented programming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use static when the function doesn't depend on a specific object that the method is being applied to. How that applies to your application depends on its design.

For instance, if you have a class for dealing with dates and times, and it contains a function to return the current timestamp, it doesn't need to be applied to a specific date object -- it's the same for any date. So it could be a static function.

Static functions may be necessary if you need to run some functions before creating any instances of the class. If you use the Factory pattern, you will use a method to create instances in the first place. This will necessarily be a static method.

Comment: I'd add that sometimes you *have* to make static functions because they are intended for use when you don't have an instance yet, for example, when you need to *get* or fabricate an instance. Getting the instance of a Singleton class is a great example. The Factory pattern is another.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb it is best to stay away from static code whenever possible.  When you start using static calls you are *tight-coupling* the class into your code.  This makes it difficult to test your code later on when you want to swap out the static class for a mock class.  For most cases, it is best to use dependency injection instead.

That said, like sugar and salt, static code has its place and if you are careful and utilize it correctly you can have applications that work well with your static code.  For example, the singleton pattern depends on a static method to attain the reference to the singleton itself.  Static methods work nice for basic utility functions that do not need to depend on any class state.

In the end, it is best to stay away from them.  Some folks call them evil (they are not), but if you are using them, at least take the time to explore *why* you are using them and if the design of a static class is better than a concrete one for your particular use case.

Comment: this is what I expect to see, thanks man

Comment: SO should not be used to express opinions (opinion-based questions are expressly off-topic). So answers to this question should be based on the technical differences between static and non-static functions, not preferences about OO design principles.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately it is hard to answer this (off-topic) question without some form of opinion about use cases for static code.  The OP didn't ask for technical differences of static/non-static function, they asked for reasons to use or not use static code.  Even you mention design patterns in your answer, which I feel is a great way of expressing a "best practice" (opinionated?) way of informing the OP on when to use static code.  Speaking of off-topic, now that I am thinking of it, I forgot to flag this as too broad.....

Answer (score 1):

You can use static function if you need a function without calling the Class constructor before.
For example, i have a class like this :

```
class Animal {
 .............
 .........

  private function name() {
    // This will print name of Animal that you assign through $this
    echo $this->$name;
  }
}
Animal->name();
```

at another case, you want to implement a function to your class that doesn't require $this for that. And the second :

```
class Animal {
 .............
 .........

  public static function splitName($name) {
    // In this case your source is assigned by parameter, not by $this
    echo explode("-",$name);
  }
}
Animal::splitName();
```

If you are beginner, to easy remember is 'If you use static function, data source come from param. and then for Private function the data came from $this' ... got it ? Ask me more by comment, james

Comment: You're not calling `Animal::name()` correctly, it needs to be `$animal->name()`.

Comment: And you left out the argument to `Animal::splitName`. Although I don't see why that should be static. It should use `explode("-", $this->name)`.

Comment: are you saying if it's not static then the data came from $this? above u mentioned private function,but a function and be either private or public.

Comment: @Barmar : the main concept of static function is you can implement a function inside a class that can stand-alone run without any extra protected, private variable

Comment: @jameslebron :yes james, if you declare a function, i sure you will process a data. usually if you build a CLASS. you will familliar with $this. $this is a local variable that allow all function inside CLASS to access it. And you will need data source, Alright ?
A static function just need you to input all data from param the return without initalize the CLASS and call it staticaly. In private function you need to initialize it before

Comment: `Animal->name()` is still wrong. You need to put an object before `->`, not a class.

Comment: If you know, why you don't edit my answer @Barmar ? Talkless do more :D

Comment: Editing should only be used for trivial changes, like fixing typos or formatting. Not correcting logic errors.

Comment: @MichaelAntonio if your code wrong pls edit it, otherwise you mislead newbie like me lol..